# On Mac, how can I set a default program to open *all* unknown files?

Tags: macos, mac

On Mac I often have files that are unknown to OS X. Opening the file results in a popup asking me to choose a file or search the Mac App Store.

I know that for files I can set the default program to open all files with that specific extension. What I am aiming at now is to set a default program on my Mac to open *all* files that cannot be automatically opened by another program. (Because 99% of the time I want to open those files in TextWrangler.)

So in short: I don't want to set a default program for files of a specific extension, but for all unknown files.

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206974/how-to-setup-a-specific-application-to-open-all-files-with-unknown-extension

Answer (score 1):

That isn't an option because some files you wouldn't want to open.  As a result you  you can select by file ext.  hold down option while right clicking and select open with and select text wrangler.  This will change the default for all files with the same extension.

I like just dragging the file and dropping it on the text wrangler app (I keep it in my dock.  This doesn't require you to change the default program but opens the file just the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can still point a particular doc at TextWrangler, and it should be able to 'change all'...

I have the same scenario often - shell scripts or various text files that need to be modified - - - right-click on the first (or Command+I) and set to textwrangler....

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. This only changes the default program for a specific extension, which I then would have to do many times.